# RcppEigen install failure on Ubuntu 18 LTS: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument ‘__m128’

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rcpp, install.packages, rcppeigen

I think this question is a duplicate: [RcppEigen install failure on Ubuntu 20.04: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument ‘__m128’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67795127/rcppeigen-install-failure-on-ubuntu-20-04-warning-ignoring-attributes-on-templ)

However I don't think the solution proposed will work for me as I do not have root access to the machine. I am using R in a conda environment on Ubuntu 18 Bionic Beaver. Attempting to install RcppEigen gives a bunch of warnings (snippet of which are shown), then the make command abruptly fails:

```
../inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/DenseCoeffsBase.h:55:30: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::packet_traits<double>::type {aka __vector(2) double}' [-Wignored-attributes]
    
../inst/include/Eigen/src/Core/CoreEvaluators.h:960:8: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'Eigen::internal::packet_traits<double>::type {aka __vector(2) double}' [-Wignored-attributes]

make: *** [/home/4469722/miniconda3/envs/r_env/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:175: fastLm.o] Error 1

ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RcppEigen’

* removing ‘/home/4473331/R/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-library/3.6/RcppEigen’
```

Any help is appreciated. Here is my session info:

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /home/4469722/miniconda3/envs/r_env/lib/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!   Now, with all due respect, this is i) on a non-CRAN platform and ii) on a severely outdated version of R and iii) on a severely outdated OS version.  So why do you want a current RcppEigen?  I see a mismatch here.   Ubuntu 18.04, which you chose, has a pre-made r-cran-rcppeigen too.  Of course it is old but so is Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Thanks! I am constrained because I need to use the remote server at my university to run this code (I can get everything working fine on my own PC, but I need to deploy to the server to run large jobs). I don't maintain the server or have sudo permissions, so Ubuntu 18 is what I'm stuck with.  R is not installed on the server either. My supervisor has an R environment installed with conda on the server which I have been using for R until now - so AFAIK I'm stuck with the R version I'm using. Need the RcppEigen as it is a dependency of the transport package - version probably doesn't matter

Comment: OK well with to your hint to use the pre-made Ubuntu 18 version of  r-cran-rcppeigen, I did manage to get this package installed. Thank you!