# How to suppress warning -Wignored-attributes using __m128 on templates?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, warnings

I've [this](https://godbolt.org/z/cG8hd95q8) basic code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <emmintrin.h>

template <typename T>
struct SRCDecimator {
    SRCDecimator() {
    }
};

int main()
{
    SRCDecimator<__m128> srcDecimator4;
}
```

which output this warning:

*warning: ignoring attributes on template argument '__m128' [-Wignored-attributes]*

Question are:

1. what's the reason about this warning of a "common type"?
2. how can I suppress that warning? not sure I can change the native __m128 object

Thanks

Comment: Related: [Implication of GCC warning: ignoring attributes on template argument (-Wignored-attributes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676311/implication-of-gcc-warning-ignoring-attributes-on-template-argument-wignored)

Comment: Also more related: [warning: ignoring attributes on template argument ‘__m128’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72103543/rcppeigen-install-failure-on-ubuntu-18-lts-warning-ignoring-attributes-on-temp)